# Drawing 3D plot in R programming

Tags: r

```
library(mgcv)
model1 <- gam(EE ~ te(Load, Gradient, k=4,  bs=c("tp", "tp")), data = dipasEE) 
x <- range(dipasEE$Load)
x <- seq(x[1], x[2], length.out=20)
y <- range(dipasEE$Gradient)
y <- seq(y[1], y[2], length.out=20)
z <- outer(x,y,
           function(Load,Gradient)
             predict(model1, data.frame(Load,Gradient)))
p <- persp(x,y,z, theta=30, phi=30,
           col="yellow",expand = 0.5,shade = 0.2, ticktype = "detailed",
           xlab="Load", ylab="Gradient", zlab="EE")
obs<- trans3d(dipasEE$Load, dipasEE$Gradient,dipasEE$EE,p)
pred<- trans3d(dipasEE$Load, dipasEE$Gradient,fitted(model1),p)
points(obs, col="red",pch=16)
segments(obs$x, obs$y, pred$x, pred$y)
predict(model1)
pd <- data.frame(Load = seq(0, 21.5, by = 0.5), Gradient = 15)
predict(model1,newdata=pd)
Output:
[enter image description here][1]
```

# How to plot the points for newdata=pd in the 3d plot? Below is the Output for above code with Plots. Need to Point more plots for newdata=pd.

# 3 D Plot Graph

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIMoY.png
```